# Setup Visual Studio's Server Explorer to work with postgresql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, postgresql, asp.net-core

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio's Server Explorer to connect to a postgresql database. I am using ASP.NET Core & EF Core with npgsql.

This feature works fine with SQL Server but there's no option to connect to postgresql and my attempts (including this [guide](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html#overview)) have failed. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC with MSBuild .NET Core, but I could downgrade to 2015 if necessary for this to work.

My aim is to be able to edit data from within VS and have a development 'localdb' similar to the one provided with SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by downloading the [ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/), entring my credentials, then adding it to Visual Studio through 'Add Connection'. For some reason only the 32-bit version worked (on my 64-bit machine).